# Identifying from which method it is coming

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two methods both returning the view:

```
public function method1()
{
  return ('view1');
}
```

and

```
public function method2()
{
  return ('view1');
}
```

In the view i want to edit some changes regarding from which method it is coming:

Something like this in view1:

```
@if(coming form method1)
{
   This is coming from method1,
}
@endif
```

How can this be acheived? Currently i'm just making two separate views for so minor change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a flag in method

```
public function method1()
{
  $flag = 'method1';
  return ('view1', compact('flag'));
}

public function method2()
{
  $flag = 'method2';
  return ('view1', compact('flag'));
}
```

and in the view check for the flag

```
@if ($flag == 'method1')
   This is coming from method1
@elseif ($flag == 'method2')
   This is coming from method2
@endif
```